# How does `({...})` return a value?

Tags: c, gcc

I recently found this GCC macro:

```
#define max(a,b) \
   ({ typeof (a) _a = (a); \
       typeof (b) _b = (b); \
     _a > _b ? _a : _b; })
```

I didn't realize before I saw this code, that a block of code `{...}` can somehow return value in C.
**1) Could you give me a hint how this works?**

Though, I usually was able to achieve the same result by abusing the comma operator:

```
#define max(a,b) \
    (typeof (a) _a = (a), \
     typeof (b) _b = (b), \
     (_a > _b ? _a : _b))
```

or if it was only for side-effect I would use `do { ... } while(0)`

**2) What is the preferred way of doing this?**

Comment: that could become a protected question! many C(and C++, I believe) programmers don't know that `({ ... })` is an GCC-extension and not part of C language. IMHO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`({ ... })`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.1/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs) construct is a gcc extension.

So is the [`typeof`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.1/gcc/Typeof.html#Typeof) operator.

A `MAX` macro (note the conventional use of all-caps) is easy enough to write:

```
#define MAX(a, b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))
```

It does evaluate one of its arguments more than once, so you shouldn't invoke it as, for example, `MAX(x++, y--)`.  The use of all-caps serves to remind the user that it's a macro, not a function, and to be careful about arguments with side effects.

Or you can write a function (perhaps an inline one) for each type.

Comment: +1 Wow :-|, really didn't know about `({ ... })`. They should totally put it in the language.

Comment: Thanks for the [`({ ... })`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.1/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs) link! It is always hard to google with just punctuation.

Answer (score 10):

It is a GCC extension.  The comma operator doesn't work:

```
// C89, doesn't work...
#define max(a,b) \
    (typeof (a) _a = (a), \
     typeof (b) _b = (b), \
     (_a > _b ? _a : _b))
```

The comma operator only works with expressions, and `typeof(a) _a = (a);` is a declaration, not an expression.  It is not really possible to write an equivalent macro without either GCC extensions or C11, which has `_Generic`.  Note that `typeof` is als a GCC extension, so you don't gain any portability by eliminating `({...})` unless you eliminate `typeof` too.

Here is a C11 version, note how verbose it is by comparison (and it only handles two types!).  C11 isn't even supported yet, good luck trying to find a compiler to test this:

```
// C11
static inline int maxi(int x, int y) { return x > y ? x : y; }
static inline long maxl(long x, long y) { return x > y ? x : y; }
#define max(x, y) _Generic((x), \
    long: maxl(x,y), \
    int:_Generic((y), \
        int: maxi(x,y), \
        long: maxl(x,y)))
```

In portable C99, you can write a macro or inline function that achieves the same effect, *except* it will only work for one type per macro.

```
// C99
static inline int maxi(int x, int y) { return x > y ? x : y; }
```

In C89/C90, I can't think of any way to write the macro in such a way that it won't evaluate `x` or `y` twice.

Comment: Please don't write an answer that says nothing. Just bide your time and write a good answer. It will get plenty of upvotes if it is good. No need to try and claim the question as your own.

Comment: Sorry, I am on an unfamiliar terminal and I'm trying to save drafts so I don't lose what I write.  Not really trying to "claim the question as my own."